# flickr oembed not returning images larger than 500px wide

Tags: api, flickr, oembed

I'm trying to use oEmbed in my website. I need to use large images (at least 700px wide).

I try to use this code:

```
http://www.flickr.com/services/oembed?url=http://www.flickr.com/photos/majdal/4035572180/sizes/l/in/photostream/&format=xml&minwidth=1000
```

But the image returned is less than 700px wide...

```
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2632/4035572180_3c8015790e.jpg
```

Is there a way to force flickr to return larger images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have corrected this issue and now Flickr oembed call will return higher resolution images (up to 1024px in biggest dimension).

-flickr staff

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a internal flickr restriction. At least I already saw this discussion inside the flickr api group one year ago and there was no answer: http://www.flickr.com/groups/api/discuss/72157623040761625/

Comment: great to see that flickr fixed that restriction in the latest api revision

Answer (score 0):

Are those images larger than 700px on Flickr? Any chance you could use the PHP API? (http://phpflickr.com/)

Comment: yeah, the image is definitely larger than 700px. I'm using django-oembed, so i'm bound to this...